# href link not redirecting to Page properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am regenerating a ecommerce site from Scratch

On the working site this link

```
<a href="../*WebsiteName*/product-category/women/">Sidebar – Left</a>
```

redirect to URL

```
 http://*WebsiteName*/product-category/women/
```

and Page renders properly ..

But on my Server ..

```
<a href="../product-category/women/">Sidebar – Left</a>
```

redirect to

```
 http://*WebsiteName*/product-category/women/
```

in Browser with  404 "Not found"

.. when I remove last "/" and put html extension . the page appears

I search for some post regarding relative Path and they suggest to set path for root directory by using "../".

I search for url rewriting post and htaccess file , but the first step they mention is that href attribute redirect to html or php file... then we mask the last php or html Extension path ..

I put this htaccess file on the root of the site folder ..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.htm[L,QSA]
```

But in my case my href link is not even redirecting to htm page

I am  not able to find any relevant post ..what is I am missing ?

Comment: can you try using `./` at the beginning or you can add website name instead.

Comment: `<a href="./*WebsiteName*/product-category/women/">Sidebar – Left</a>` or `<a href="http:xyz.com/*WebsiteName*/product-category/women/">Sidebar – Left</a>`

Comment: Instead of using `../` at the beginning of the URL use `/` only. `/` stands for the root directory, not `../`.

Comment: the links are not issue  "../product-category/women/"   is only right URL .. "./"    "/" are not giving me right path My Problem is it redirecting to a directory , it should Redirect to HTML page

Comment: Why are you rewriting your html files to php files?

Comment: oh that is typo mistake  , edited the post .. that is also not helping

Comment: Try adding a base tag to header of your document, **<base href="/">** , May be this hels.

Comment: You mean like  this "<head> <base href="/"> .."  .